# Get ABS(absolute value) in laravel Query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel framework and I'm looking for how to write Query in order to get the absolute value(in short ignoring the + and - sign and only display number from database.
I know we can use Abs in order to get it. But I don't know how do it.
Take a look at my code:

```
$users = DB::table('transaction_details')->

Join('ledger','transaction_details.ledger','=','ledger.Name')->

groupBy('ledger.Name')->select(
    'ledger.CrDr as CrDr',
    'transaction_details.ledger as Name',
    'transaction_details.amount as Debit',
    'ledger.OpeningBalance as openingBalance'
)->get();
```

In above query i want `ledger.openingBalance` value to be absolute.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DB::raw` for the `ledger.openingBalance` select column to avoid it from being quoted by the Query Builder:

```
DB::table('transaction_details')
  ->join('ledger','transaction_details.ledger','=','ledger.Name')
  ->groupBy('ledger.Name')
  ->select(
      'ledger.CrDr as CrDr',
      'transaction_details.ledger as Name',
      'transaction_details.amount as Debit',
      DB::raw('ABS(ledger.OpeningBalance) as openingBalance')
  )->get();
```